# C# Developing a simple Sales Prediction system?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, encog

I'm quite new to machine learning, I've been trying to develop a system to predict the number of sales for a year depending on the previous examples given using Encog Neural Network but I couldn't quite understand how to develop it. It's quite simple actually:

**x axis (Year) =>**

2000,2001,2002,2003,2004

**y axis (No. of sales) =>**

30,25,45,60,55 respectively

So if a question was given so as to predict the sales of 2005, how can I implement this in a neural network? Do you guys have a sample code maybe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sigh, one cannot simply ask a simple question on this community anymore..

Comment: Do you have more than one variable?

Comment: The only variables would be the x and the y sir. As in, only the No. of Sales could be asked for a given year @jorgenkg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Here's an illustration of an approach to predict or classify the "future".

We can create a neural network with X input signals and 1 output signal. The input signal should be the Y values from the previous years, and the neural network will calculate its predicted output signal as the Y value for the subsequent year.

If you are new to machine learning I should also tell you that you would need a huge dataset in order to create a "well working" neural network. It will be far from reliable if you just input 10 historical data points from your own sales log during the training.

[image]

Comment: Since your using Encog, here is a time-series example from Encog.  https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/guide/timeseries